# SAPUI5 remove item from Combobox

Tags: combobox, sapui5

I am using a Combobox, in the controller the binding is done below and for some reason I need to delete few items from the Combobox So in `onAfterRendering` method I am removing the items as below.

```
this.byId("idaddrusages").removeItem(3);
```

The items were removed, however If I access the view in the same session it is throwing an error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: adding element with duplicate id
>   '__xmlview0--container-component---newAddress--idNewAddUsagesItm-__xmlview0--container-component---newAddress--idAddressUsages-3'

If I refresh the page with a new session the items were removed from the Combobox.

View

```
<ComboBox id="idaddrusages" >
  <core:Item id="idNewAddUsagesItm" key="" text=""/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: 1) your combobox has only 1 item and you are removing the 3rd
2) by default, if you refresh the page you have the same result
3) it would be good to post more about your code - clearly there are other import pieces of code
4) why are you doing it inside afterrendering? Why not update a model or implement a filter?

Comment: No, my comobobox has 6 items

Comment: In your code your combobox has 1 item
<ComboBox id="idaddrusages" >
<core:Item id="idNewAddUsagesItm" key="" text=""/>
</ComboBox>

Comment: Controller - t.byId("idaddrusages").setModel(A, "oAddrUs");

Comment: View : <ComboBox id="idaddrusages" >
<core:Item id="idNewAddUsagesItm" key="{oAddrUs>AdrKind}" text="{oAddrUs>Textlong}"/>
</ComboBox>

Comment: please provide the complete source code. Also please adapt your code in the question and not in the comments. Still, with the changes you provided, your combobox has only 1 item.

Comment: DOM Manipulation is not  working here n this case, hence we have removed from the model it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM Manipulation is not working here n this case, hence we have removed the items from the model it self.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong way to declare combobox

```
<ComboBox id="idaddrusages" >
<core:Item id="idNewAddUsagesItm" key="" text=""/> // don't give id to item hence it complaints about duplicate id's
</ComboBox>
```

Secondly, better way to do is use local json model using your own defined json data or from odata model and bind the ComboBox as shown below

```
<ComboBox id="idaddrusages"
            items="{
                path: '/CollectionName'

            }">
            <core:Item key="{key}" text="{text}" />
        </ComboBox>
```

Then you can remove items by just updating your model the way you like and combobox should be updated automatically

Let me know if it works for you.